# Error 500 on javascript call to jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-chrome, firefox, httprequest

I have a jsp file and at the very bottom I have the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location.href = "#<%= request.getQueryString() %>";
</script>
```

Which essentially is there to jump to an anchor point (for when a user is coming back from a page to take them to where they were last).

In IE it works fine but in Chrome and Firefox I get an internal error 500.

If I disable javascript it works. So I'm guessing it's something to do with the location.href?

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I took out all the javascript so it wasjust 'request.getQueryString() and it worked fine, so it's the location.href causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems window.location is a bit flaky across browsers but the replace() method is fine. All I am doing is changing the anchor so you can get there directly through hash property.

```
window.location.hash="";
window.location.replace(window.location+"<%= request.getQueryString() %>);
```

Hope this helps anyone. i.e. use replace() method not location= or location.href=